# Parse Redis HGETALL object in Node.js

Tags: node.js, redis

I'm trying to parse an HGETALL object in Node.js.

---

In Redis CLI:

```
> HGETALL userList
```

returns

```
1) "19578616521094096601"
2) "User 1"
3) "1682930884780137383"
4) "User 2"
```

---

In Node:

```
var redis = require('redis')
,   r = redis.createClient();

console.log(r.HGETALL('userList'));
```

returns

```
true
```

---

I would like to parse the userList object as JSON or an array but I can't seem to figure out how to pull data out of it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

RedisClient use callback to return the result.

Exemple:

```
var redis = require('redis'),
    r = redis.createClient();

r.hgetall('userList', function(err, results) {
   if (err) {
       // do something like callback(err) or whatever
   } else {
      // do something with results
      console.log(results)
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks racar. Using the code above I was then able to loop through the object properties using `for (var userID in results) {}`.

Comment: note that `for key in object` is not generally the best approach. Better to use `Object.keys(object).forEach(key => {...});`

Comment: why is `for..in` "not generally the best approach"...? I'm fairly sure its faster, and it lets you break early.

Comment: I just came across this answer searching stuff about `hgetall`, and saw this comment. Beware that with `for..in` you iterate over inherited enumerable properties too, and you might not want that. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25052758/for-in-vs-object-key-foreach-without-inherited-properties

Answer (score 1):

Straight from redis.io's own [Node.js guide](https://redis.io/docs/connect/clients/nodejs/):

```js
await client.hSet('user-session:123', {
    name: 'John',
    surname: 'Smith',
    company: 'Redis',
    age: 29
})

let userSession = await client.hGetAll('user-session:123');
console.log(JSON.stringify(userSession, null, 2));
/*
{
  "surname": "Smith",
  "name": "John",
  "company": "Redis",
  "age": "29"
}
 */
```

As long as you have the correct collection name / key, your case should be straightforward, and you should get back an object (if there are multiple key-value pairs. If you're storing in each property a JSON string, don't forget to parse it before using it as an object!