# In JavaScript is Object.keys().forEach() less memory efficient than a simple for...in loop?

Tags: javascript, loops, object, ecmascript-5

Imagine you have a very large JS object, containing millions of key/value pairs, and you need to iterate over them.

[This jsPerf example](http://jsperf.com/object-keys-vs-for-in-with-closure/10) shows the main ways to do it, and outlines the speed differences.

What I wonder though is: using `Object.keys()` would have a different impact on memory compared to the other looping methods, since it needs to create the "index" array that contains all the object keys first?

Are there any optimizations in the source code that prevent this?

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is lazy iteration over the properties of an object or array. This is not possible in ES5 (thus not possible in many implementations, such as  node.js). We will get this eventually.

Memory-wise, both `for ... in` and `Object.keys.forEach` will load the whole set of attributes to memory. How much actual memory is used in each JS engine can vary significantly. You should always test your code on different scenarios and using several engines to determine which works best on your application.

Comment: Thanks Iván! Is there any data already available on how these two methods perform memory-wise? If I understand correctly, even if both load the whole set to memory, `Object.keys()` still needs to duplicate the space taken by object keys, in order to return the array containing them, right?

Comment: It's not like that, as Object.keys is a native method. So, for starters, it's quite faster than the other methods (it's more performance-wise optimized). 

As for memory consumption, it depends on engine implementation (most of them use a hashMap for faster access and memory reduction).

Also, be aware that using `for...in` with `hasOwnProperty()` to match only the non-inherited properties creates a function for each key, thereby increasing memory consumption and reducing performance quite a bit.

Comment: Hi Iván, sorry but native or non native, `Object.keys()` still returns an array, and that array needs to be stored somewhere. Object keys are strings, hence passed by value (if you modify an element in the returned array, you're not touching the original object key). In my understanding this means memory usage will be duplicated for object keys when the method is invoked.

Comment: You're right about getting duplicate keys and using twice as space. What I meant is that ALL iterators cause this data duplication. What I meant is that Object.keys tends to cause less memory usage as it's a native method and therefore, creating the key array is a process much more optimized than the rest of the methods. I apologize if I didn't explain myself correctly.

Comment: When you say "ALL iterators cause this data duplication", what do you mean exactly? How does for example "for...in" iterate over object keys? Do you know how this is implemented in the source code? Cheers

Comment: I mean that iterators' data (basically, all keys) is loaded into memory before being executed. This is true for both the Object.keys and the for... in iterators. This is what I mean by "duplication".

Comment: Do you have a reference to the source code of how these two methods are implemented?

Comment: No, just talking from experience (using Chrome's DevTools to monitor memory use and performance) and some pages I looked up during my research. I don't work with C/C++ so I didn't look the code up.

Comment: `Object.keys()` generates and returns a new array each time it is invoked, it doesn't just point to an existing array used internally in the object. Thus, in my understanding, it takes more memory. Try this: `var a = {foo: 'bar'}`, then `var b = Object.keys(a)`, then `var c = Object.keys(a)`, you will see that `b === c` returns `false`.

Answer (score 0):

well the problem is that Object Keys combine the for..in with hasOwn property so depending on what your ultimate goal is, they can be exclusive or interchangeable. as for the benchmark you saw them your self it all comes down to engine implementation. check this answer for more info

[for-in vs Object.key forEach without inherited properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25052758/for-in-vs-object-key-foreach-without-inherited-properties)

Comment: Hi Dayan, how do you know the implementation details of `Object.keys()`, have you seen the source code? I suppose if it were internally using `for...in` with `hasOwnProperty()`, then there would not be such large performance differences.

Comment: no i haven't seen the source code of every JS engine, but is a known fact that not all browsers build its JS interpreter the same way. so what might be true for some may not be for other.