# In Javascript (V8) why does forEach on an array consume much more memory than a simple for loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, memory, optimization, v8

I'm performing some simple data validation on a large set of data in Node.js (version v7.5.0, with a matrix of 15849x12771 entries). The entire data set is in memory for now, for performance reasons. Therefore it is critical for me to reduce the amount of memory consumed to a theoretical minimum (each number representing 8 bytes in JS).

Please compare the following ways of achieving the same thing.

*with `forEach`*

```
  regressData.forEach((yxa, yxaIndex) => {
    yxa.forEach((yx, yxIndex) => {
      if (!_.isFinite(yx)) {
        throw new Error(`non-finite entry at [${yxaIndex}, ${yxIndex}]`);
      }
    });
  });
```

This consumes all of my node process' memory at 4GB+, causing it to never (until my patience runs out anyway) finish the loop (I guess it will use slower swap memory).

And then the identical version with a typical `for`:

```
  for (var yxai = 0, yxal = regressData.length; yxai < yxal; yxai++) {
    const yx = regressData[yxai];
    for (var yxi = 0, yxl = yx.length; yxi < yxl; yxi++) {
      if (!_.isFinite(yx[yxi])) {
        throw new Error(`non-finite entry at [${yxai}, ${yxi}]`);
      }
    }
  }
```

This consumes virtually no extra memory, causing the validation to be done in less than a second.

Is this behavior as expected? I had anticipated that because the `forEach`s have closed scopes there would be no issues of additional memory usage when compared to a traditional `for` loop.

**EDIT: standalone test**

*node --expose-gc test_foreach.js*

```
if (!gc) throw new Error('please run node like node --expose-gc test_foreach.js');

const _ = require('lodash');

// prepare data to work with

const x = 15849;
const y = 12771;

let regressData = new Array(x);
for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
  regressData[i] = new Array(y);
  for (var j = 0; j < y; j++) {
    regressData[i][j] = _.random(true);
  }
}

// for loop
gc();
const mb_pre_for = _.round(process.memoryUsage().heapUsed / 1024 / 1024, 2);
console.log(`memory consumption before for loop ${mb_pre_for} megabyte`);
validateFor(regressData);
gc();
const mb_post_for = _.round(process.memoryUsage().heapUsed / 1024 / 1024, 2);
const mb_for = _.round(mb_post_for - mb_pre_for, 2);
console.log(`memory consumption by for loop ${mb_for} megabyte`);

// for each loop
gc();
const mb_pre_foreach = _.round(process.memoryUsage().heapUsed / 1024 / 1024, 2);
console.log(`memory consumption before foreach loop ${mb_pre_foreach} megabyte`);
validateForEach(regressData);
gc();
const mb_post_foreach = _.round(process.memoryUsage().heapUsed / 1024 / 1024, 2);
const mb_foreach = _.round(mb_post_foreach - mb_pre_foreach, 2);
console.log(`memory consumption by foreach loop ${mb_foreach} megabyte`);

function validateFor(regressData) {
  for (var yxai = 0, yxal = regressData.length; yxai < yxal; yxai++) {
    const yx = regressData[yxai];
    for (var yxi = 0, yxl = yx.length; yxi < yxl; yxi++) {
      if (!_.isFinite(yx[yxi])) {
        throw new Error(`non-finite entry at [${yxai}, ${yxi}]`);
      }
    }
  }
};

function validateForEach(regressData) {
  regressData.forEach((yxa, yxaIndex) => {
    yxa.forEach((yx, yxIndex) => {
      if (!_.isFinite(yx)) {
        throw new Error(`non-finite entry at [${yxaIndex}, ${yxIndex}]`);
      }
    });
  });
};
```

Output:

```
toms-mbp-2:mem_test tommedema$ node --expose-gc test_foreach.js
memory consumption before for loop 1549.31 megabyte
memory consumption by for loop 0.31 megabyte
memory consumption before foreach loop 1549.66 megabyte
memory consumption by foreach loop 3087.9 megabyte
```

Comment: In your first example, you reference `yxaIndex` in the inner loop. How does your memory consumption go if you remove that reference in the `new Error` line.

Comment: That seems strange... can you make that reproducable with a predefined dataset and an isFinite (dummy) function, so one could run this standalone?

Comment: By "no extra memory", what do you mean in hard numbers?

Comment: @CFrei I have updated the question with a standalone runnable test. @Bergi see the test, the `for` loop uses 0.3 megabyte extra, wheras the `forEach` uses several gigabytes.

Comment: @DavidThomas thanks for the suggestion, I gave it a try but it didn't seem to affect memory consumption. I added a standalone test to my question so you can try for yourself.

Comment: The answers in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28640729/in-javascript-is-object-keys-foreach-less-memory-efficient-than-a-simple-for) will probably help you. It seems that `for ... in` and `Object.keys.forEach` are well known at being memory hogs. I tried even with node v7.6.0 and it still ran out of memory. I suppose V8 may rewrite their implementation of these functions in the future to stop them loading the full arrays into memory, rather than just iterating through them with indexes.

Answer (score 10):

**2022 Update: This question, and this answer, are obsolete.**
The "new execution pipeline" mentioned in the original answer below has been enabled for several years now.

Original post below (in case you're still running 2017-era Node):

---

(V8 developer here.) This is an unfortunate consequence of how `Array.forEach` is implemented in V8's old execution pipeline (full codegen + Crankshaft). In short, what happens is that under some circumstances, using `forEach` on an array changes the internal representation of that array to a much less memory efficient format. (Specifically: if the array contained only double values before, and `forEach` has also been used on arrays with elements of other types but not too many different kinds of objects, and the code runs hot enough to get optimized. It's fairly complicated ;-) )

With the new execution pipeline (currently behind the `--future` flag, will be turned on by default soon), I'm no longer seeing this additional memory consumption.

(That said, classic `for` loops do tend to have a small performance advantage over `forEach`, just because there's less going on under the hood (per ES spec). In many real workloads, the difference is too small to matter, but in microbenchmarks it's often visible. We might be able to optimize away more of `forEach`'s overhead in the future, but in cases where you know that every CPU cycle matters, I recommend using plain old `for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)` loops.)

Comment: interesting! how would I enable `--future` with node.js? I don't see it when I run `node --v8-options`

Comment: See https://medium.com/@bmeurer/help-us-test-the-future-of-node-js-6079900566f#.t38ycyhzp .

Comment: @jmrk is this still relevant today?

Comment: @Elec No. The new execution pipeline has been enabled for years. (You can also very easily verify that yourself: just run the given test case.)