# update value of each item in associative array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a JavaScript associative array, say:

```
var myArray = new Object();
myArray["id1"] = "completed";
myArray["id2"] = "notCompleted";
myArray["id3"] = "started";
```

How can I update value of each item in this array, so that output should be,

```
myArray["id1"] = "newValue";
myArray["id2"] = "newValue";
myArray["id3"] = "newValue";
```

Comment: Just do what you did in the first code block of your question. A loop block will help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get all property name array using **[`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)** and then iterate over them update property value using **[`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)** method.

```js
var myArray = new Object();
myArray["id1"] = "completed";
myArray["id2"] = "notCompleted";
myArray["id3"] = "started";

Object.keys(myArray).forEach(function(k) {
  myArray[k] = 'newVal';
});

console.log(myArray);
```

---

Faster way  using a `while` loop.

```js
var myArray = new Object();
myArray["id1"] = "completed";
myArray["id2"] = "notCompleted";
myArray["id3"] = "started";

var names = Object.keys(myArray),
  i = names.length;

while (i--) {
  myArray[names[i]] = 'newVal';
};

console.log(myArray);
```

Comment: Should i prefer this answer over `for (var prop in myArray)...`  if yes why?

Comment: @A.R. `forEach` is compatible for IE9+. Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach. Whereas `for-in` is compatible with IE6+. So in case you are looking to support for old browsers, you might want prefer http://stackoverflow.com/a/38868298/5102631

Or else this is fine. No as such difference. You can attach polyfill anytime, although native levels code are faster.

I think @Pranav agrees to this!

Comment: @Ayan what do you mean by 'You can attach polyfill anytime'? Can you please explain?

Comment: @A.R. As we are speaking of the compatible issues for `forEach`
Check this mdn link - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach.

Scroll down, you would get a pollyfill. A pollyfill is a substitute code to make the feature compatible in the browsers which natively dont support it.

Like in an IE8 browser, you can use this code.

Comment: @A.R. : `forEach` is much slower one..... but you can use `while` loop to make it faster....... there may be browser compatibility issues with `Object.keys()`.... check here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys#Browser_compatibility , For implementing polyfill option for older browser : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys#Polyfill ..... For the comparison refer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25052758/for-in-vs-object-key-foreach-without-inherited-properties

Answer (score 2):

- Use for in loop
- Its always advisable to use [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) to iterate across only the non-inherited properties.

```js
var myArray = new Object();
myArray["id1"] = "completed";
myArray["id2"] = "notCompleted";
myArray["id3"] = "started";

for (var prop in myArray) {
  if (myArray.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
    myArray[prop] = 'newValue';
  }
}

console.log(myArray);
```